# how can i group the data below by ID and accumulate the entries in La,Lm and Le

Tags: pandas

```
ID           Ls  L_m        Le
10001511    270  241.0  663                                                      
10001514    8    95.0   345    
10001516    104  298.0  389   
10001511    7    100.0  717  
10001514    224  296.0  548  
10001516    443  340.0  366
```

Where ID is id  numbers, Ls,l_m and Le are floating numbers.I want to group it by ID and have one result for Ls(like 270 +7 fir ID: 10001511),L-m and Le.

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: Maybe you want `print df.groupby('ID').sum()` ?

Comment: yes....i actually used df.groupby('ID').sum() to get the seaired output...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df.groupby('ID').sum()
```